# UWP MapControl TransitFeaturesVisible="False" not hiding all transit options

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to use TransitFeaturesVisible="False" to hide the standard icon used on the map for London Underground stations with no success so far. Its hiding most options such as bus stops but its not hiding airport symbols either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's a "Feature Request". You could submit your feature request on [WPDev UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/)